# Switching layer views according to main cameras

Tags: camera, video-sequence-editor, scene, viewlayers

how can I tie the view layer used for the rendering to the main camera?

Here's more context. I am making a video for a boardgame with multiple camera angles and various game cards/figurines settings demonstrating the game rules.

I am using view layers for each game settings, as in

- layer one for the first round
- layer two for a specific game situation
- layer xxx for the end game settings" etc,
  and cameras for my various angles of the game board. I tied my cameras to markers on my timeline in order to manipulate them more easily following the delivery of the narrator's speech or the video's pacing.

For now, I keyframed the *View Layer> Use for Rendering* option to each of my layers following their sequence order but it's a pretty janky solution when I want to move everything a few frames forward/backward, and more annoying, I cannot see in real time how and what will be rendered since the viewlayer stays the same through the video unless I manually select it in the top-right menu.

In a nutshell, I want to be able to manipulate easily multiple states of the same scene on the same timeline.

What's the best way to do that?

I am aware of the *Scene* setting but I must admit I don't know how to use it, it seems pretty overkill for what I'm trying to do.